# IMPORTRANGE: multiple hyperlinks within one cell, importing this cell data into another sheet and retaining separate clickable links

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I currently use a Google sheet to hold data x1 row per item. I use one particular cell to hold two separate hyperlinks within (x2 website addresses), both links are relevant/in relation to this item.

I want to keep the structure of having two separate clickable hyperlinks in one cell, but I also need to import this cell data (these two links) into another Google sheet, is there a way of using IMPORTRANGE and retaining these two separate hyperlinks (ensuring clickable & still x2 separate links within one cell), or converting them into hyperlinks when importing into another sheet?

Thank you in advance

I've created two dummy sheets with data for testing & to help visualise

Sheet Name: "Static" & Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JS40eNGUAmBqQJqmdX4PhWtm6GEVQP64CoxO_DooZYM/edit#gid=0

[image: Static]

Sheet Name: "Imported" & Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rhnULIcbkSMCp8AONa7UwTQz77uHn443VuwYjty2xFs/edit#gid=0

[image: Imported]

I've used `=IMPORTRANGE("1JS40eNGUAmBqQJqmdX4PhWtm6GEVQP64CoxO_DooZYM","Static1!A1:D")`

To pull data from 'Static' sheet (tab: 'Static1') into 'Imported' (tab: 'Imported1')

I'm hoping to get clickable links in column 'D' of the 'Imported' sheet

I've added different variations i.e. the hyperlinks are renamed in 'Static' sheet as "Link 1" & "Link 2", I've added a few rows with full URLs addresses (no re-naming), and a couple with full URLs and with an empty line in between - I'm not too fussed with how they look to be honest (ideally it would be nice to have 'Link 1' & 'Link 2') but mainly just looking to have x2 imported URLs within same cell that remain/become clickable after importing

This is because I'll also be iframe/embedding the 'Imported' sheet afterwards.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Either a screenshot of your sheet or a sample sheet so that we'll be able to visualize what we can do to help you out on this.

Comment: Thanks Diego & @MikeSteelson much appreciated, I've now created dummy data & sheets within overview also added a bit more information, I'm hoping I've covered everything, I've also added the IMPORTRANGE formula within the 'Imported' sheet showing my current roadblock, thanks again :)

Comment: Would creating a copy/duplicate of the sheet suffice using copyTo?

Comment: to copy, I use getValues/setValues for numeric and string values, and getRichTextValues/setRichTextValues for the column where there is links

Comment: Thank you so much, your efforts are really appreciated - I must apologise as I'm still finding my way around scripts, I'm using Google sheets quite regular now so really trying to teach myself (I do sometimes get a little confused with some of the terminology lol, so might take me a while to do research to understand bits hehe), is it also possible to use this function and import say the top 5 items with the highest quantity & specific columns? (sort by column 'c' highest to lowest & limit to return 5 rows and selecting column A,C & D), thanks again

Comment: I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is a new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question by including the detailed information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoSanchez understood, no problem will do, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

**Option 1:**
This is fairly straightforward. It just copies the Static1 sheet unto a destination sheet and names it Imported.

```
function createCopy2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1vM-0nBBlhVvRQ3vvXwkWlecENM7CVuv8iei3cl0uRQI"); 
  var ds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Static1');
  sheet.copyTo(ds).setName('Imported');

}
```

**Option 2 (incomplete):**

This is what I have done so far, but this still throws an error `Exception: Illegal Argument` at this line `var text = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(linkval[i]).setLinkUrl(0,7,urls1[i]).setLinkUrl(7,13,urls2[i]).build();`.

(P.S: Just wanted to throw this out here if in case someone would find this logic useful/not to waste my efforts practicing JS lol).

Kudos to Mike Steelson for providing a working answer.

```
 function createCopy() {

  //Creates a full copy of the source sheet without Hyperlinks (AKA importrange in script form)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1vM-0nBBlhVvRQ3vvXwkWlecENM7CVuv8iei3cl0uRQI"); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0].getSheetValues(1,1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
  var ds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ds.getRange(1,1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).setValues(sheet);
  Logger.log(sheet);

  var link = ds.getRange(2,4, ss.getLastRow(), 1);
  var linkval = link.getValues();
  var urls1 = ds.getRange(2,5, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var urls2 = ds.getRange(2,6, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

for(i=0; i < ss.getLastRow(); i++){
 var text = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(linkval[i]).setLinkUrl(0,7,urls1[i]).setLinkUrl(7,13,urls2[i]).build();  
} 
}
```

Comment: the solution is probably to integrate the custom function I provide in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the urls by a custom function in addition of the IMPORTRANGE

```
function extractUrls(range) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var rngAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\)/).pop().trim(); 
  var urls = activeSht
    .getRange(rngAddress)
    .getRichTextValue()
    .getRuns()
    .reduce((array, e) => {
      var url = e.getLinkUrl();
      if (url) array.push(url);
      return array;
    }, []);
  return ([urls])
}
```

[image]

### edit

in your situation

```
function createCopy() {
  var id = "1JS40eNGUAmBqQJqmdX4PhWtm6GEVQP64CoxO_DooZYM"
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0]
  var values = source.getRange(2,1,source.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues()
  var richTxt = source.getRange(2,4,source.getLastRow()-1,1).getRichTextValues()
  var output = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('output_v2')
  output.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)
  output.getRange(2, 4, richTxt.length, richTxt[0].length).setRichTextValues(richTxt)
}
```